# repaint() method in java not working properly

Tags: java, paint, repaint

am doing that program to paint the mouse location in a panel , the program works fine but after like 10 seconds it stops painting the points... any help?

```
   import java.awt.Color;
   import java.awt.Graphics;
   import javax.swing.JPanel;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class Draw extends JPanel {
public static  int newx;
public static  int newy;

   public void paint(Graphics g) {    

  Mouse mouse = new Mouse();
  mouse.start();

int newx = mouse.x;
int newy = mouse.y;
 g.setColor(Color.blue);  
   g.drawLine(newx, newy, newx, newy);
   repaint();




   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setBackground(Color.white);
  frame.setSize(2000,2000 );
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.getContentPane().add(new Draw());
  frame.revalidate();
  frame.getContentPane().repaint();


  }
 }
```

Comment: What is `Mouse` class? show its code..

Answer (score 2):

You call `repaint` within the `paint` method, causing an infinite loop. [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) are preferred for running periodic updates on components.

For custom painting in Swing the method `paintComponent` rather than `paint` should be overridden not forgetting to call `super.paintComponent`.

Comment: that's true , it's supposed to be an infinite loop

Comment: That's why the the code is locking up. The code that changes `newx`, `newy`, etc. should call `repaint` on the `JPanel` instead

Comment: Calling `repaint()` doesn't call `paint()` or `paintComponent()` imediately. It only schedules for it to be done when it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

`public void paint(Graphics g)` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`.

And you isn't supposed to call repaint() inside this method.

You should add an mouse listener outside this method, too.

An adapted example from [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)

```
public class MouseMotionEventDemo extends JPanel 
                                  implements MouseMotionListener {
    //...in initialization code:
        //Register for mouse events on blankArea and panel.
        blankArea.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        ...
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       Point point = e.getPoint();
       updatePanel(point); //create this method to call repaint() on JPanel.
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    }


    }
}
```